# Is it possible to generate SAS (Shared Access Signature) with write permission for given directory in azure blob storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

Our blob storage account structure:

container name: **simple**

inside this container we have blobs:

```
aa/one.zip
aa/two.zip
bb/ss.zip
bb/dd.zip
```

Is it possible to generate SAS with write permission for aa “directory”, but no access for bb “directory”?

With Amazon AWS we can easily create restrictions based on object/blob prefix name, but I can't find similar functionality in azure storage sdk for java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today, it is not possible to do so at the folder level because as such there's no folder in Azure Blob Storage.

You can either create a SAS at a container level or at the blob level. If you want your users to only upload files with certain names, you can very well create a SAS with write permission on the blob name. Blob need not be present when you're creating a SAS.

Thus when your users upload a file using this SAS, it will be saved as a blob that you have chosen to name. So what you will do is create a SAS for a blob named `bb/ss.zip` and give it to a user. When the user uploads the file, it will be saved as `bb/ss.zip` in your blob container.