# Is there a way to set path level read/write permissions in GCP and Azure? (like AWS)

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, permissions, credentials

For a project it is important for me to get access to a user's cloud directory, but only a particular path. If possible, I want this to be as specific as possible, configured to something like "read access in this directory", and "write access in this directory", and nothing else. (I don't want to ask for too much access to a user's storage account.)

It is possible to grant path level permissions with a programmatic access key in AWS by creating this JSON file. (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

I need to do the same thing for GCP and Azure. I have been researching this for a while and I haven't found anything exactly similar to the above for AWS.

For Azure I found the SAS token, which could be set to a particular blob/item. (When you click three squares to right of blob it says "generate SAS")-- however this option doesn't seem to be possible for a folder. There is the more global option of the Storage Account, but this is too global. Doesn't seem possible ([Is it possible to generate SAS (Shared Access Signature) with write permission for given directory in azure blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270955/is-it-possible-to-generate-sas-shared-access-signature-with-write-permission-f?rq=1) )

For GCP, from this ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819707/granting-directory-level-permissions-for-google-cloud-storage-rest-apis#:~:text=As%20explained%20in%20the%20documentation,%22directory%22%20in%20Cloud%20Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819707/granting-directory-level-permissions-for-google-cloud-storage-rest-apis#:%7E:text=As%20explained%20in%20the%20documentation,%22directory%22%20in%20Cloud%20Storage) ) it just seems like this is not possible. Right now I'm just making a Service Account with Storage Admin and json credentials, however this is too global as before. There seems to be this idea of fine-grained access (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#choose_between_uniform_and_fine-grained_access ) however I'm not sure if this is what I need/ how this would work.

Is this just a flaw of Azure/GCP that they cannot provide this like AWS can? /Does anyone know how to do this; any advice appreciated. So far it just doesn't seem possible but I'd really like to find a work-around.

Comment: This question is a bit broad (across multiple clouds), and more of a documentation-request question, but... for Azure, take a look at the docs for ADLS gen 2 (essentially hierarchical storage), which I believe covers the type of fine-grained access control you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, great, thank you! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: The problem is, that this is only for ADLS gen 2 storage, while I am looking for how to do this in blob storage, though it's close to what I want

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism that would allow you to set different permissions to individual directories or folders stored inside a GCP bucket (it's a design decision).

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49821123/12257250):

> As explained in the documentation, there are no such thing as
> directories in Cloud Storage. As far as Storage is concerned, there
> are only buckets and inside them objects/files that may or may not
> have "/" in their name.
>
> Due to this design choice, there's no option to set permissions on a
> "directory" in Cloud Storage.

But - you can set [individual permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions) based on ACL's to an objects inside a bucket (as long is it has [fine-grained access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#choose_between_uniform_and_fine-grained_access) enabled).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think there's no such thing as 'paths/directories' in AWS either formally but they still allow this option. I think the individual permissions might not work, but thank you though :/

Comment: Thanks for the comment - if you think my answer helped you in any way I'd appreciate an upvote or accept :)